# Most Powerful Hypothesis Test for an exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I was given the following question in a practice exam. $X\sim f(x;\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta x}I(0<x<\infty)$ with the following hypothesis $H:\theta \ne 1 \text{ vs } A: \theta=1$ The question asks to find a UMP test of size $\alpha=.05$

I figured that since the distribution is exponential then it has a monotone likelihood ratio in $X$. If I consider the one tail test $H: \theta>1$ vs $A: \theta=1$ then by the Neymar pearson lemma there exists a UMP test of size $\alpha=.05$ of the form $X<t_1$ where $t_1$ is chosen to produce an $\alpha=.05$. Note since our original hypothesis is two tail, then the one tail test will beat ours in power;therefore, there cannot exist a UMP test for this hypothesis. The best we can hope for is an UMPU Test. Is this correct.

Comment: FYI, if you haven't thought about or know about it, in the future, please consider whether or not this type of question might be better suited to the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (i.e., statistics) SE site.

Comment: Yes UMP test does not exist, so proceed to find UMPU test.